# CSS not reflecting for php page even though after linking between Head Tags

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin, xampp

My CSS is not getting reflected on a PHP page. I am using Xampp server. The display.css file is in my htdocs folder only. Let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
    <?php
Php Code
    ?>
    <html>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="display.css" />
    <title>E-Library Display Section</title>
    </head>
    <center><h1>Books Available for Free Download</h1></center>
    <body>
                <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="table">
                <div class="row header">
                        <div class="cell"><Book Name</div>
                        <div class="cell">Book Description</div>
                        <div class="cell">Book Author</div>
                        <div class="cell">Book Language</div>
                        <div class="cell">Download Link</div>
                        <div class="cell">Uploader Name</div>
                        <div class="cell">Uploader Email</div>
                    </div>  
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['bookname']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['bookdesc']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['bookauthor']."</td>";
                            ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If and only if this PHP page is not in the `htdocs` folder just like the CSS file, then that's why. Add a forward slash to your `href` attribute like `href="/display.css"`.

Comment: @Zeke Yaa made the changes and it worked. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: you're welcome! Do remember to mark the answer below as correct when you're allowed to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your stylesheet link, change src to href.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="display.css" />
```

Also, you have two closed `</head>` tags and no open ones but that's not causing your problem.